# Is it possible to retrieve a delegate function database and excute it?

Tags: c#, delegates

I have a situation in which I need to validate database fields. Each field can have it's own and different validation process. 
Is it possible to define a validation function as a delegate signature in the C# code where the implementation of delegates as NVARCHAR(MAX) are in SQL database? Then on runtime I can retrieve this function from the database and execute it.

Example

```
public delegate string ValidateFunction(List<string> Params)
.
if (Row[0].TranslateFunction != null)
{
    string test = GetTargeTableValue( new List<string> { "mm" }, Row[0].TranslateFunction);
}
.
 private string GetTargeTableValue(List<string> sqlParams, ValidateFunction FieldValidation)
{
      return FieldValidation(sqlParams);
}
.
```

Row[0].TranslateFunction is in the database table of type NVARCHAR (max) and contains something like 
(SQL )

```
'string GetUom( List<string> Params)
{return Params[0].ToUpper() } '
```

Comment: Delegates are just references for functions; they contain  no code. - C# is not a scripting language. All code you want to run must be compiled. So, no, this will not work without incorporating an on-the-fly compiler in your code. Not possible for newbies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
// add NuGet package 'Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.Scripting'
   using Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting;
   await CSharpScript.EvaluateAsync("System.Math.Pow(2, 4)") // returns 16
```

or

```
var script = await CSharpScript.RunAsync(@"string GetUom( List<string> Params) {return Params[0].ToUpper() } ")
await script.ContinueWithAsync("GetUom(List<string> Params)");
```

For more information 
Please visit 
[Scripting API Samples](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples)

and [for more learning visit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6a783cc4-bb54-4fec-b504-f9b1ed786b54/create-a-anonymous-method-from-a-string)

Comment: Thank you so much, your answer helped a lot. This package is amazing, the flexibility it provides is incredible. Thanks again for the suggestion.

Comment: It's my pleasure! please mark this answer as solution.

Answer (score 1):

Create serialise-able validation classes (inherit from a base class so they all have a common root). You can set up specific objects, of the required validation type and with the required data for validation, that can be converted to serialised text and stored in your database. When you want to validate a field then you can deserialise the stored text to an object, then invoke the object against the field (better to load the rules back into memory once into a cache and use them from there, this can be slow).

Sorry I can't produce example code off the top of my head (there's a fair bit of code needed to get it all set up), but I did something similar in a previous role, where the validation rules were stored in the application's config file.

Comment: Thank you very much for your time and answer. In my case, the code will not be updated or changed once published in production while each  platform will have the need of some changes only possible through Dlls or Database. therefore, this answer will not be practical in this situation.